Empty city, sound wave knocks out small group containing a killer
I'm loolking for a movie in which there is a city with almost no-one, perhaps a maximum of only 5 or 6 people will be there, 3 women and 3 men. At certain time intervals the entire city there is a sound(?) wave by which knocks them all out.
In one particular scene, a woman will start to smoke a cigar and that cigar will have some substance that will get caught on her hand and kills her. In one scene a guy gets killed by turning a leaking pipe off which triggers some arrows from long distance and gets shot.
Lastly it's discovered that one among them is the killer. There will be a police officeer and a woman and one man. Finally the killer will be shot by the girl.

Please add possible release year, language, and country so that it can help identify this movie.

Is that "Mindhunters", which has been released in 2004-2005 ? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mindhunters)

It's definitely "Mindhunters", you should post it as an answer

Yes, this is 'Mindhunters', go for it Shindo92

The movie is "Mindhunters", which has been released in 2004-2005. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mindhunters)
"A group of mindhunters travels with their instructor to a small island off the coast of North Carolina to complete their final training exercise..."
